# How can I link a Microsoft 365 Developer Sandbox to an Azure Student account so that they share a tenancy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-quickstart?tabs=Microsoft365) tutorial on developing with Microsofts Graph Data Connect. The tutorial states:

> - The Azure subscription must be in the same tenant as the Microsoft 365 tenant. Microsoft Graph Data Connect will only export data to an Azure subscription in the same tenant, not across tenants.
> - Your Microsoft 365 and Azure tenants must be in the same Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenancy.

I already have an Azure account with an Azure for Students subscription. I signed up to the Microsoft 365 Developer Program and created a new sandbox. This creates a totally new tenant with a corresponding admin@[MYTENANT].onmicrosoft.com account.

The 365 sandbox has an Azure Directory, but no subscription or ability to create new services. The admin account cannot be used to sign up for a new free subscription, attempting to create an Azure free account results in a "Your current account type is not supported" message.

Is there a way to link these two accounts together so I can create an app in Azure that uses Graph Data Connect to access the dummy data in the 365 Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change your azure subscription to a new directory. (It might be blocked by policy however)

You'll need a user who exists in both directories, and who is an owner on the subscription. In the portal, click the "Change Directory" button on the ribbon and follow the prompts. Note, the directory change will delete all RBAC role assignments and possible some other configurations, but if this is a learning subscription there's probably not a lot that can't be recreated.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest/offer/how-to-change-directory-tenants-visual-studio-azure